# Not getting the option to select schema in apex while loading data

Tags: oracle-apex

I am trying to load data through Excel sheet in version 4.2 using options :

Go to SQL workshop->utilities->data workshop ->data load

But I am not able to select schema. Here is a screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Does your workspace actually have (a) schema(s) assigned to it?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the reply
I found out the issue:
There were 2 options in the data workshop-
a)New table
b)existing table

Had to change the option in data workshop from new table to existing table.